# tkinterモジュールでテキストボックスに値を入力したものを取得して、外部ファイルに１セルに文字列を格納したい

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

今回やりたいことは、GUI画面からテキストボックスに値を入力したのを、外部ファイル（CSVに書き込むためのファイル）に格納したい。
二つのファイルがあり、一つはGUIファイル(sample_tkinter.py),もう一つが実行ファイル(merge.py)になります。

GUIの機能は、

１テキストボックス
２テキストボックスの値を取得するボタン
３閉じるボタン

・word1にテキストボックスの値を取得できていると思っていますが、以下のようなエラーができてしまいます。
①writer.writerow(word1)
_csv.Error: iterable expected, not function
② writer.writerow(word1)
_csv.Error: iterable expected, not NoneType

・スクリプトを二つに分ける意味は特になく、二つに分けるというのが依頼内容ということです。

・CSVファイルの詳細として、特定のことは決まっていなく、とりあえずテキストボックスの値をCSVに書き込みをしたいだけになります。

コードが以下です。

**sample_tkinter.py**

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

entry=tk.Entry()
entry.place(x=20,y=30)

button=tk.Button(text="OK")
button.place(x=150,y=29)

word1=""
def click():
    global word1
    word1=entry.get()
    #entry.delete(0,tk,tk.END)
    label=tk.Label(text=word1)
    label.place(x=20,y=50)

button["command"]=click

def close_window():
 root.destroy()

botton1=tk.Button(text="閉じる",command=close_window)
botton1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**merge.py**

```
import csv
from sample_tkinter import word1
with open("sample.csv","w",encoding="shift-jis")as csvfile:   writer=csv.writer(csvfile,lineterminator="\n")
    print(word1)
    writer.writerow(word1)
```

上記については解決しましたが、書き込んだCSVが、一文字がセル一つと文字列が分解して表示されてしまいます。
例えば、テキストボックスの値が”あいうえお”だとすると、CSV上では
A　| B　| C　| D　| E
あ | い | う | え | お　 　
以上のように表示されます。
こちらの解決方法をご教授願います。

Comment: スクリプトを2つに分ける意味や前提条件はありますか？ 2つに分けることで複雑化して問題が発生しやすくなっていませんか？ それから表示されたエラーメッセージはその2行だけでは無いのでは？ エラーメッセージは省略せずに表示されたままの全てをテキストで提示してください。 そして作成したい結果のCSVファイルの詳細情報も追記してみてください。

Answer (score 0):

この場合、`word1`は入力されたテキストでは無く、`def click():`で定義された関数のオブジェクトが入っています。
それに該当するのは`word1=click`の処理ですね。

そのために文字列やリストを対象とする`writer.writerow()`のパラメータに指定するとエラーとなります。

最小限の変更で済ますとしたら、`sample_tkinter.py`の以下の部分を：

```
def click():
    word=entry.get()
    entry.delete(0,tk.END)
    label=tk.Label(text=word)
    label.place(x=20,y=50)

word1=click
```

こちらのように変更することでしょう。`word1=click`は削除しておくことです。

```
word1=''

def click():
    global word1
    word1=entry.get()
    entry.delete(0,tk.END)
    label=tk.Label(text=word1)
    label.place(x=20,y=50)
```

---

**追記：**

`word1`の内容が何であれ、まとまった一つのデータとして扱いたい場合は、`merge.py`の以下の行を：

```
    writer.writerow(word1)
```

こちらに変更すれば良いでしょう。

```
    writer.writerow([word1])
```

ただし入力した文字列にカンマ(`,`)を含んでいたりすると、全体をダブルクォーテーション(`"`)で囲まれるなどの処理が自動的に行われるので、Pythonの`csv`,`csvwriter`モジュールの仕様を把握して使用してください。